# setstate no esta funcionando en react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal, usestate

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario el cual envia la informacion a una funcion y esta a su vez manda una funcion timeout para simular que el procesado de informacion està en progreso, mientras eso ocurre se muestra un modal en pantalla, la cosa es que cuando intento cerrar ese modal dentro de la funcion timeout y intento mostrar otro cambiando el estado de ese modal que quiero mostrar a true, este no se muestra y el estado queda en falso, al quedar este estado en falso pues obviamente el modal que quiero mostrar no lo hace, lo curioso es que esto mismo lo probe en android y funcionaba correctamente pero en ios sale como este tipo de bug. dejo el còdigo

```
const [isFetching,setisFetching]=useState(false)
const [Visible4, setVisible4]=useState(false)
    const submit=()=>{
        const regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
        if(fullName==="" || email==="" || nickname==="" || password==="" || rePassword===""){
            //mensaje
            setVisible(true)
        }else if(!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/.test(email)){
            setVisible2(true)
        }else if(password!==rePassword){
            setVisible3(true)
        }else if(password.length<8 ){
            setVisible5(true)
        }else if(!regularExpression.test(password)){
            setVisible6(true)
        }else{
            setisFetching(true)
            asyncfunction().then((r)=>{
                isFetching(false)
                setVisible4(true)
            })
        }
    }

    return(
         <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"height"} style={styles.containerKeyBoard}>
            <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={{marginTop:40, height:5}}></View>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.containerTop}>
                        <View style={styles.containerTop2}>
                                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.backButton} {...touchProps}><Image style={styles.leftArrow} source={BackArrow} /></TouchableHighlight>
                                <Text style={styles.mesadokoText}>MESADOKO</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={styles.topText}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', marginTop:20}}>
                        <TextInput
                        style={styles.fieldEmail}
                        placeholder="Full Name"
                        placeholderTextColor="#ACACAC"
                        onChangeText={(e)=>setFullName(e)}
                        defaultValue={fullName}
                        >    
                        </TextInput>
                        <TextInput
                        style={styles.fieldPassword}
                        placeholder="Email"
                        placeholderTextColor="#ACACAC"
                        onChangeText={(e)=>setEmail(e)}
                        defaultValue={email}
                        >    
                        </TextInput>
                        <TextInput
                        style={styles.fieldPassword}
                        placeholder="Nickname"
                        placeholderTextColor="#ACACAC"
                        onChangeText={(e)=>setNickName(e)}
                        defaultValue={nickname}
                        >    
                        </TextInput>
                        <TextInput
                        secureTextEntry
                        style={styles.fieldPassword}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        placeholderTextColor="#ACACAC"
                        onChangeText={(e)=>setPassword(e)}
                        defaultValue={password}
                        >    
                        </TextInput>
                        <TextInput
                        secureTextEntry
                        style={styles.fieldPassword}
                        placeholder="Confirm password"
                        placeholderTextColor="#ACACAC"
                        onChangeText={(e)=>setrePassword(e)}
                        defaultValue={rePassword}
                        >    
                        </TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.containerBottom}>
                        <TouchableHighlight {...touchProps2} style={styles.signButton} onPress={submit}><Text style={styles.signButtonText} activeOpacity={0.9}>LET'S GO!</Text></TouchableHighlight>
                        <Text style={styles.bottomText3}>By clicking LET'S GO, you agree</Text>
                        <View style={styles.containerBottomText}><Text style={styles.bottomText2}>to our Terms,</Text><Text style={styles.bottomText}> Privacity</Text><Text style={styles.bottomText2}> and</Text><Text style={styles.bottomText}> Data Policy</Text></View>
                    </View>
                    {Visible ? <ModalFunctionality img={OctopusError} message={"Error! there are unfilled fields"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#F82D2D"} vw={changeVisibilityModal}/>  : null}
                    {Visible2 ? <ModalFunctionality img={OctopusError} message={"Error! Please enter a valid email"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#F82D2D"} vw={changeVisibilityModal2} /> : null}
                    {Visible3 ? <ModalFunctionality img={OctopusError} message={"Please make sure your passwords match"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#F82D2D"} vw={changeVisibilityModal3} /> : null}
                    
                    {isFetching
                        ? <ModalFunctionalityLoading img={Loading} message={"Loading"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#1EB7D9"} vw={changeVisibilityModal4} />
                     
                     :null
                     }
                     {Visible4? <ModalFunctionality img={OctopusNofication} message={"Your info has been saved"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#1EB7D9"} vw={changeVisibilityModal4} /> 
                     :null}
                     {/* {Visible4 ?<ModalFunctionalityLoading img={Loading} message={"Your info has been saved"} heg={150} wid={180} vw={changeVisibilityModal4} /> 
                     :null} */}
                    {Visible5 ? <ModalFunctionality img={OctopusError} message={"Error: the password must contain at least 8 characters"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#F82D2D"} vw={changeVisibilityModal5} /> : null}
                    {Visible6 ? <ModalFunctionality img={OctopusError} message={"Error: password should contain at least one number and one special character"} heg={120} wid={130} bgcolor={"#F82D2D"} vw={changeVisibilityModal6} /> : null}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}
```

Comment: react no tiene problemas, debe ser algo de tu componente modal muestra el codigo de tus modales.

Comment: Y para modal en react nativo cambia en ios y android busca una libreria que este bien echa por que ios 13 cambiaron las cosas, ios usa escenas y ya no es solo 1 como antes.  Si quieres poner una vista por delante de todo. Pero si es 1 vista por delante de todas en una vista padre no deberia haber problemas con lo standard de react hacer una logica.